# Creating MultiPolyline with leaflet Js

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

In the past (leaflet version 0.7) I used the code

```
var multipolyline = L.multiPolyline([[[35.10418, -106.62987],[35.19738, -106.875],[35.07946, -106.80634]],[[35.11654, -106.58318],[35.13142, -106.48876],[35.07384, -106.52412]]],{color: 'red',weight:8}).addTo(map);
```

for creating a layer with multiple polylines.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Eine OSM Karte mit Leaflet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map',
{
center: [35.10418, -106.62987],
zoom: 10
});
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
var multipolyline = L.multiPolyline([[[35.10418, -106.62987],[35.19738, -106.875],[35.07946, -106.80634]],[[35.11654, -106.58318],[35.13142, -106.48876],[35.07384, -106.52412]]],{color: 'red',weight:8}).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not work with the current leaflet version 1.0.0 and I do not find the class multiPolyline in the leaflet documentation (http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html). So I think that it is removed.

How can I create a layer with many polylines on it? Do I have to create each polyline and add it to the layer or is there another function for accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the changelog you can just use L.Polyline:

> Removed MultiPolyline and MultiPolygon classes since multiple rings are now handled by Polyline and Polygon classes respectively. Layers with multiple rings now perform much better (since each is now physically a single path object instead of being a FeatureGroup of layers).

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md